# Control Components' execution in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm working in react.js, I would to avoid the execution of 2 components meanwhile the user input some text, the workflow is like this:

1. the user enter some text
2. the text's length is displayed
3. A second component validate text's length
4. A third component split the text

This is my sourcecode:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ValidateText from './ValidateText';
import CharText from './CharText.js'
import './hwork02.css';

/* general purpose:
1. Input any text
2. Validate its lenght (min and max)
3. Display each letter as a char
4. if the user clicks on each one, it has to be deleted
class based components
*/
class TextMe extends Component{
    
    state = {
        myText: '',
    }

    updateTxtHandler = (event) => {
        //ejemplo de codigo mala practica y que no es ES6
        this.setState({
            myText: event.target.value,
        });

    }

    render(){   
        return(
            <div className="cajatipo1">
                <h1>Homework02: Text2Chars</h1>
                <div>
                    <h3>Please type any text you want</h3>
                    <input type="text" width="80" placeholder="Type any text greater than 3 characters"
                    value={this.state.myText}
                    onChange={this.updateTxtHandler}
                    />
                    <h3>Using "state" to update this control simultaneously:</h3>
                    <label>{this.state.myText}</label> 
                    <p>
                        <ValidateText myTxtLength={this.state.myText.length} />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <CharText text2Char={this.state.myText.split("")} />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>    
        )
    }
}

export default TextMe;
```

The problem I'm dealing with is how to avoid the execution of ValidateText and CharText for the first time? I would like they are running when the user is typing text. So, any suggestions will be awesome.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your design could be questionable (it feels weird to use a React component to perform validation, a simple value checking the value should do it, then you trigger messages based on the return), but here is a simple solution: do not init the state before the user inputs anything.

```
class TextMe extends Component{

state = {}

updateTxtHandler = (event) => {
    //ejemplo de codigo mala practica y que no es ES6
    this.setState({
        myText: event.target.value,
    });

}

render(){   
    return(
        <div className="cajatipo1">
            <h1>Homework02: Text2Chars</h1>
            <div>
                <h3>Please type any text you want</h3>
                <input type="text" width="80" placeholder="Type any text greater than 3 characters"
                value={this.state.myText || ""}
                onChange={this.updateTxtHandler}
                />
                <h3>Using "state" to update this control simultaneously:</h3>
                <label>{this.state.myText}</label> 
                <p>
                    {this.state.myText && <ValidateText myTxtLength={this.state.myText.length} />}
                </p>
                <p>
                    {this.state.myText &&<CharText text2Char={this.state.myText.split("")} />}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>    
    )
}
}
```

Please adjust the the conditions to your needs.

Here, while the state is undefined, there is neither `<ValidateText/>` nor
`<CharText/>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your approach and even more for your comment, these are my first steps in react, I don't have totally clear how to design my components, I'm just following a tutorial, as a matter of fact, I'm working on understand how props and states work. I'll keep in mind what you said about validation. All the best

Comment: Do not hesitate to mark the answer as accepted if it helps, so that it can help others too! :)

Comment: OK thanks @sjahan, as a matter of fact, it didn't work for me, I'm coding my own solution and as soon as I can I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would like to share my code approach which solved the functionality I needed. the magical line is this one:                         {this.state.myText.length>0 ?, take a detailed look to the code here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ValidateText from './ValidateText';
import CharText from './CharText.js'
import './hwork02.css';

/* general purpose:
1. Input any text
2. Validate its lenght (min and max)
3. Display each letter as a char
4. if the user clicks on each one, it has to be deleted
class based components
*/
class TextMe extends Component{
    
    state = {
        myText: '',
    }

    //metodo para actualizar el contenido del textbox
    //se usa spreadOperator para no operar de manera directa el objeto
    updateTxtHandler = (event) => {
        //ejemplo de codigo mala practica y que no es ES6
        this.setState({
            myText: event.target.value,
        });
        /*
       const newText = [...this.state.myText]
       newText.myText = event.target.value
        */       
    }

    render(){   
        return(
            <div className="cajatipo1">
                <h1>Homework02: Text2Chars</h1>
                <div>
                    <h3>Please type any text you want</h3>
                    <input type="text" width="80" placeholder="Type any text greater than 3 characters"
                    value={this.state.myText}
                    onChange={this.updateTxtHandler}
                    />
                    <h3>Using "state" to update this control simultaneously:</h3>
                    <label>{this.state.myText}</label> 
                    {this.state.myText.length>0 ?
                        <p>
                            <ValidateText myTxtLength={this.state.myText.length} />
                            <CharText text2Char={this.state.myText.split("")} />
                        </p>
                    : null
                    }
                </div>
            </div>    
        )
    }
}

export default TextMe;
```